# Using Spring,MyBatis for a client server model

Tags: spring, client-server, mybatis

As per my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952490/multithreaded-server-client-in-mybatis) i was able to build a multi-threaded server client model for my application.

Now i have to migrate it to Spring (Core not MVC as of now). Can anybody please suggest again from where to start?

Googled a lot but couldn't find a decent tutorial.
If any one can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest go through [spring in action](http://www.manning.com/walls2/) first,
Then the spring by example [site](http://www.springbyexample.org/)

Additional resources

1. [Spring Source Site](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html)
2. [Krams Blog](http://krams915.blogspot.com/)

Thanks,